# Como remover a borda do texto em um componente?

Tags: java, swing

Eu tenho um programa em Java e gostaria de remover estas bordas que aparecem no texto do botão:

[image: imagem]

(As bordas vermelhas foi na edição as que eu quero remover são aquelas azul escuro dentro das vermelhas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definir [**`Component#setFocusable()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) com `false` faz com que essa borda ao redor do texto seja removida. Na verdade isso é um indicativo que o componente está com foco.

```
JButton foo = new JButton();
foo.setFocusable(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode remover como o [renan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4808) falou, porém vai ficar sem as referencias de *focus* para acessar os botões com o <kbd>tab</kbd>  e a barra de espaço por exemplo.

```
setFocusable(false);
```